# JavaScript and jQuery code to return function by var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on small api to get content from my database. I want to show data in a JavaScript/jQuery function according to variables I declared.

example

```
<script>
function dataset() {
var url = "www.example.com";
var name = "Mini Api";
ver version = "1.00";

this.return url;
this.return name;
this.return version;
}
</script>
```

How I intend to use it

```
<script>
minapi = new dataset();
//here I want to return only name 
alert(minapi.name);
</script>
```

Please any idea of how to get this done?

In addition, is there a way to create jQuery function to execute once page load without using this `$( document ).ready(function() {});`?

Comment: What doesn't work from what you've done? That code looks like it should function properly.

Comment: No, `this.return` isn't valid js unless `this` is an object with property `return`, and that's not the case.

Comment: Is this `ver version = "1.00";` intended to be `var`?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question. That construct you have in your second question will run when the page is loaded. You could also place the script element containing the code you wish to run at the bottom of the HTML, just above the `</body>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function dataset() {

   var myData = {
       url: "www.example.com",
       name: "mini api",
       version: "1.00"
   };

   return myData;

}

var myVar = dataset();
console.log(myVar.name);
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/1455d5z3/

Comment: Putting the above code in `<script>` tags will fire when the page loads - you do not need `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are attempting to do. I fixed `ver` and assigned properties correctly.

```
function dataset() {
  var url = "www.example.com";
  var name = "Mini Api";
  var version = "1.00";

  this.url = url;
  this.name = name;
  this.version = version;
}
```

There might be better ways to do this depending on your situation, but this does give the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this.

```
function dataset() {
  var url = "www.example.com";
  var name = "Mini Api";
  var version = "1.00";

  this.returnUrl = function (){
    return url;
  } 
  this.returnName = function (){
    return name;
  } 
  this.returnVersion = function (){
    return version;
  } 
}

 var minapi = new dataset();
 alert(minapi.returnName());
```

Refer [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrrtsteg/16/)